# I am trying to implement a substitute teacher in react for a time table it's not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have a react app named timetable and in that I have 3 components App.js, timetable.js and substitute-form.js,

//Expected

The basic idea is when I enter the name of a teacher that is absent and select a substitute teacher from the drop down and click create time table I want the new timetable to be created as substitute teacher in place of absent teacher.

//Actual

When I add a name in absent teacher and select a name from substitute teacher drop down and select create time table it's not updating the time table.

```
//App.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Timetable from "./timetable";
import SubstituteForm from "./substitute-form";

const App = () => {
  const [timetable, setTimetable] = useState([
    {
      time: "8:00 AM",
      monday: "Math",
      tuesday: "Science",
      wednesday: "English",
      thursday: "History",
      friday: "PE",
    },
    {
      time: "9:00 AM",
      monday: "Math",
      tuesday: "Science",
      wednesday: "English",
      thursday: "History",
      friday: "PE",
    },
    {
      time: "10:00 AM",
      monday: "Math",
      tuesday: "Science",
      wednesday: "English",
      thursday: "History",
      friday: "PE",
    },
    {
      time: "11:00 AM",
      monday: "Math",
      tuesday: "Science",
      wednesday: "English",
      thursday: "History",
      friday: "PE",
    },
    {
      time: "12:00 PM",
      monday: "Lunch",
      tuesday: "Lunch",
      wednesday: "Lunch",
      thursday: "Lunch",
      friday: "Lunch",
    },
    {
      time: "1:00 PM",
      monday: "Math",
      tuesday: "Science",
      wednesday: "English",
      thursday: "History",
      friday: "PE",
    },
    {
      time: "2:00 PM",
      monday: "Math",
      tuesday: "Science",
      wednesday: "English",
      thursday: "History",
      friday: "PE",
    },
    {
      time: "3:00 PM",
      monday: "Math",
      tuesday: "Science",
      wednesday: "English",
      thursday: "History",
      friday: "PE",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Timetable timetable={timetable} />
      <br />
      <SubstituteForm timetable={timetable} setTimetable={setTimetable} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;`
```

```
//Substitute-form.js

import React from "react";

const SubstituteForm = ({ timetable, setTimetable }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const absentTeacher = e.target.absentTeacher.value;
    const substituteTeacher = e.target.substituteTeacher.value;
    setTimetable(
      timetable.map((classPeriod) => {
        const updatedClassPeriod = { ...classPeriod };
        Object.keys(updatedClassPeriod).forEach((key) => {
          if (updatedClassPeriod[key] === absentTeacher) {
            updatedClassPeriod[key] = substituteTeacher;
          }
        });
        return updatedClassPeriod;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label for="absent-teacher">Absent Teacher:</label>
      <input type="text" id="absent-teacher" />
      <br />
      <label for="substitute-teacher">Substitute Teacher:</label>
      <select id="substitute-teacher">
        <option value="Mrs. Smith">Mrs. Smith</option>
        <option value="Mr. Jones">Mr. Jones</option>
        <option value="Ms. Williams">Ms. Williams</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Create Timetable</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SubstituteForm;
```

```
//timetable.js

import React from "react";

const Timetable = ({ timetable }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
      </tr>
      {timetable.map((classPeriod) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{classPeriod.time}</td>
          <td>{classPeriod.monday}</td>
          <td>{classPeriod.tuesday}</td>
          <td>{classPeriod.wednesday}</td>
          <td>{classPeriod.thursday}</td>
          <td>{classPeriod.friday}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
};

export default Timetable;
```

[image]

Comment: What is `e.target.absentTeacher`?

Comment: There is no information that tells who teaches what

Comment: In the code that I provided, e.target.absentTeacher.value refers to the value of the absentTeacher input element in the form.

In JavaScript, e is an event object that is passed to an event handler function (such as the handleSubmit function in this case). The target property of the event object refers to the element that triggered the event (in this case, the form element).

The absentTeacher input element is an HTML element with an id attribute of "absent-teacher". It is accessed using the e.target object and the id attribute like this: e.target.absentTeacher.

Comment: The value property of an input element refers to the current value of the element. In this case, e.target.absentTeacher.value refers to the current value of the absentTeacher input element.

Comment: No, it doesn't it throws an error. HTML elements don't have properties like that. I changed this code to use refs, but still, it's impossible to know which time period should be replaced, because there is no teacher information in time period

Comment: I got it, I have given the absent teacher and periods connection and its swapping the names fine